# twitter does not follow CARD meta tags (OGP) for the link first Time Used it work afterwords

Tags: twitter, facebook-opengraph, twitter-card

I have added necessary meta tags for twitter cards and Cardtype is 'summary'.
when I try to tweet any URL it does not follow CARD meta tags (OGP) for the link first Time. and it just shows as it is. now when I try same link again it works fine and shows expected result.

I tried this with another websites too.. It behaves the same?
Is there any reason behind this? Why I can't see the effect of Twitter CARD for the 1st time I try any link?